# New to Coding Very confused

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm new to coding in general and I'm trying to make a sprite change texture so it has a walking animation but I can't seem to figure out how to apply a wait() or something to my code.

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_up"):
    vel.y -= 1
    facingDir = Vector2(0, -1)
    $LilBoiTexture.texture = load("res://LilBoiAssets/LilBoiBackward.png")
    
    $LilBoiTexture.texture = load("res://LilBoiAssets/LilBoiBackward2.png")
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm trying to change from the first texture to the second one within idk 0.5, or something ill mess with it if i can figure out what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way of doing this instead of changing sprite image manually. You can use "AnimatedSprite" node as shown in the [tutorial](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/2d/2d_sprite_animation.html). Here are the steps:

1- Add an AnimatedSprite node to your character.
2- In properties of AnimatedSprite,  Frames-> select new SpriteFrames.
3- Click SpriteFrames you just created, another menu will appear at the bottom of editor. Drag and drop your animation images to center of this menu.
4- Change animation name from default to something else (for example walkback).
5- In your code you just need to do this:

```
if Input.is_action_pressed("move_up"):
    $AnimatedSprite.play("walkback")
else:
    #  you can also play an idle animation if you have one
    $AnimatedSprite.stop()
```

Comment: i dont know how this site works and how to make that look better

Comment: Make what look better?